# Inverse of a set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a function $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ defined by

$−1 + 4x$, if $x \ge 0$

$x$, if $x \lt 0$

I want to know what $f^{-1}(\{y \in \mathbb R: y \lt 0\})$ is. I've been reading Halmos' Naive Set Theory and from what I've learned, if $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, then $g^{-1}(B)$ is just the set of real numbers $\{x \in \mathbb R: g(x) \in B\}$. Going by this, $f^{-1}(\{y \in \mathbb R: y \lt 0\})$ would just be the set of numbers $\{x \in \mathbb R: f(x) \in \mathbb R^-\}$, $\mathbb R^-$ being the negative reals, excluding $0$.

That seems decently clear in my head, but I noticed that f is not injective, therefore it can't have an inverse. So how can I talk about $f^{-1}$ if it can't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f^{-1}$ isn't an actual function in this context. It is just a convenient notation, since it lines up with the case when $f$ is invertible. Your interpretation of it is correct.

Comment: +1 That's exactly right. I would add that $f^{-1}$ is usually called the "preimage" of $f$ in this situation.

Comment: So is it just an abuse of notation?

Comment: @AstlyDichrar yeah, pretty much.

Comment: @AstlyDichrar: Some of us use square brackets to distinguish this usage: if $f:X\to Y$, and $A\subseteq Y$, we write $f^{-1}[A]$ for $\{x\in X:f(x)\in A\}$. We also use this in the forward direction: if $A\subseteq X$, $f[A]=\{f(x):x\in A\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$f(\Bbb R)=$$
$$f((-\infty,0))\cup f([0,\frac{1}{4}))\cup f([\frac{1}{4},+\infty))$$

$$=(-\infty,0)\cup [-1,0) \cup [0,+\infty)$$
thus $$f^{-1}((-\infty,0))=(-\infty,\frac{1}{4}).$$